# Any disadvantage to leaving a read only table in unlogged mode after bulk loading?

Tags: postgresql

Loading a large table (150GB+) from Teradata into PostgreSQL 9.6 on AWS.  Conventional load was extremely slow so I set the table to "unlogged" and the load is going much faster.  Once loaded, this database will be strictly read only for archival purposes.  Is there any need to alter it back to logged when loaded?  I understand that process takes a lot of time and would like to avoid that time if possible.  we will be taking a backup of the data once this table is loaded and the data verified.

Edit:  I should note I am using the copy command reading from a named pipe for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you leave the table `UNLOGGED`, it will be empty after PostgreSQL recovers from a crash. So that is a bad idea if you need these data.